# Haml: more elegant way to write tag + ruby-expression + string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I've got the following haml-code in one of my templates:

```
%b= t ('activerecord.attributes.exercise.title') + ':'
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this? Preferrably as oneliner and without the brackets.

Comment: This is already a one-liner. Why do you think this is inelegant?

Comment: @yfeldblum Your point is valid, but I personally agree with PizzaPill that this is annoying — if you omit the parentheses in the method call and then want to add punctuation, you have to go in and add not only ` + ':'` but also the parentheses, and delete the space before the leading parenthesis to get it to look alright. It’s just gross and feels like more work than it should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this look better?

```
%b #{t 'activerecord.attributes.exercise.title'}:
```

Comment: much better, i was hoping for something like %b t 'activerecord.attributes.exercise.title' \: but i think this is the shortest we can get.

Answer (score 6):

The solution I like to use is Haml’s `surround`, `succeed`, and `precede` helpers:

```
= surround '(', ')' do
  = link_to 'available here', foo_path


= precede '*' do
  = link_to 'source', foo_path


= succeed ':' do
  = link_to 'foo', foo_path
Text following link
```

Then it’s just typing/pasting a line before the helper and indenting the helper.

Comment: Cool, didn't know these existed!